# Which is better way of passing string to List in C# highlighting listbox based on database values

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I would appreciate if someone can tell me what is the better way of defining `list` and passing a string to it

I am not sure which one to use or which one is better from performance point of view

```
var selection = "28,2,10,30,100,51";
List<string> categories = selection.Split(',').ToList();
List<string> categories = new List<string>(selection.Split(','));
```

I actually want to highlight the Listbox items based on database selection

after creating my list i loop through them & use following code to highlight the selection in the multi-selection list-box in asp.net

```
foreach (ListItem item in lstCatID.Items)
{
    if (categories.Contains(item.Value))
        item.Selected = true;
}
```

Is the the best way to do it or it can be done in any other way to enhance performance.

Comment: There is no performance problem until there is a performance problem. That being said, I think it's *cleaner* if `categories` is a Set.

Comment: I have about four to five listbox controls & i am not sure how it is actually going to be if it is small no. then it fine what should i consider if i may have to make selection from 500 - 600 articles in one of the listbox & list can grow day by day..

Comment: why even .ToList() it? An array resulting from Split will be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just using it to read value try using `IEnumerable<string>` instead if `List<string>` which is lighter and restrictive than list. When you use IEnumerable, you give the compiler a chance to defer work until later, possibly optimizing along the way. SO while using `Linq` expressions like `contains` that you are using here `IEnumerable` probably is the best bet. Apart from this many a times during desin pattern when you want to transfer list of items between 2 objects again IEnumerable is a best bet since it is more restrictive.

```
var selection = "28,2,10,30,100,51";          
IEnumerable<string> categories = selection.Split(',');

foreach (ListItem item in lstCatID.Items)
{
  if (categories.Contains(item.Value))
     item.Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: There will be no late deferral, its an array as returned from Split.  Might as well use var to declare the variable, as it will be IEnumerable<string> (and also string[], IList<string>) anyway.

Answer (score 3):

`ToList` internally calls the `List` constructor taking an argument of type `IEnumerable` so for both of your cases it would be same.

You should see: [Reimplementing LINQ to Objects: Part 20 - ToList (Jon Skeet)](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/01/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-20-tolist.aspx)

> You may be wondering why we even need ToList, if we could just create
>   a list by calling the constructor directly. The difference is that in
>   order to call a constructor, you need to specify the element type as
>   the type argument.

It would be better for you if you can time them both using [Stopwtach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) to see the difference, Also first make sure your code works and then worry about the performance. Usually performance optmization for this kind of task results in negligible improvements.